# merging 2 Queries into one

Tags: mysql, join, sum

I have the following queries:

Query 1:

```
SELECT agencies.code, 
       SUM(IF(commissions.action = 'collection', commissions.commission, 0)) as collections,
       SUM(IF(commissions.action = 'delivery', commissions.commission, 0)) as deliveries
FROM agencies
LEFT JOIN commissions ON agencies.code = commissions.origin OR agencies.code = commissions.destination
WHERE commissions.registered_at BETWEEN '2023-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2023-01-31 23:59:59'
GROUP BY agencies.code;
```

Result:

| code | collections | deliveries |
| --- | --- | --- |
| agency_01 | 15864.09 | 42779.13 |
| agency_02 | 9292.43 | 62248.09 |
| agency_03 | 7194.77 | 0.00 |
| agency_04 | 6869.13 | 42448.93 |

Query 2:

```
SELECT a.code,
       COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN parent.name = 'COMPENSATION' THEN c.amount END), 0) AS COMPENSATION,
       COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN parent.name = 'DIRECT_STRATEGIC_SUPPORT' THEN c.amount END), 0) AS DIRECT_STRATEGIC_SUPPORT,
       COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN parent.name = 'INDRECT_STRATEGIC_SUPPORT' THEN c.amount END), 0) AS INDRECT_STRATEGIC_SUPPORT
FROM agencies a
LEFT JOIN compensations c ON a.id = c.agency_id
LEFT JOIN compensation_categories cc ON cc.id = c.compensation_category_id
LEFT JOIN compensation_categories parent ON parent.id = cc.parent_id
WHERE DATE(c.registered_at) BETWEEN '2023-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2023-01-31 23:59:59'
GROUP BY a.code;
```

Result:

| code | COMPENSATION | DIRECT_STRATEGIC_SUPPORT | INDRECT_STRATEGIC_SUPPORT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| agency_01 | 57000.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |
| agency_02 | 70000.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |

I tried this query to join the above 2:

```
SELECT agencies.code, 
       SUM(IF(commissions.action = 'collection', commissions.commission, 0)) as collections,
       SUM(IF(commissions.action = 'delivery', commissions.commission, 0)) as deliveries,
       COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN parent.name = 'COMPENSATION' THEN compensations.amount END), 0) AS COMPENSATION,
       COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN parent.name = 'DIRECT_STRATEGIC_SUPPORT' THEN compensations.amount END), 0) AS DIRECT_STRATEGIC_SUPPORT,
       COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN parent.name = 'INDRECT_STRATEGIC_SUPPORT' THEN compensations.amount END), 0) AS INDRECT_STRATEGIC_SUPPORT
FROM agencies
LEFT JOIN commissions ON agencies.code = commissions.origin OR agencies.code = commissions.destination
LEFT JOIN compensations ON agencies.id = compensations.agency_id
LEFT JOIN compensation_categories ON compensation_categories.id = compensations.compensation_category_id
LEFT JOIN compensation_categories parent ON parent.id = compensation_categories.parent_id
WHERE commissions.registered_at BETWEEN '2023-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2023-01-31 23:59:59'
   OR compensations.registered_at BETWEEN '2023-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2023-01-31 23:59:59'
GROUP BY agencies.code;
```

But the result is incorrect:

| code | collections | deliveries | COMPENSATION | DIRECT_STRATEGIC_SUPPORT | INDRECT_STRATEGIC_SUPPORT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| agency_01 | 150842.24 | 440205.62 | 363660000.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |
| agency_02 | 76549.70 | 578579.74 | 502880000.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |
| agency_03 | 7194.77 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |
| agency_04 | 6869.13 | 42448.93 | 0.00 | 0.00 | 0.00 |

Even the previously correct fields of `collections` and `deliveries` for `agency_01` and `agency_2` are now incorrect.

How to join the 2 correctly?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be the answer. So far it's working:

```
SELECT agencies.code, 
       COALESCE(collections.collections, 0) as collections,
       COALESCE(deliveries.deliveries, 0) as deliveries,
       COALESCE(compensations.COMPENSATION, 0) AS COMPENSATION,
       COALESCE(compensations.DIRECT_STRATEGIC_SUPPORT, 0) AS DIRECT_STRATEGIC_SUPPORT,
       COALESCE(compensations.INDRECT_STRATEGIC_SUPPORT, 0) AS INDRECT_STRATEGIC_SUPPORT
FROM agencies
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT origin as code, 
         SUM(IF(action = 'collection', commission, 0)) as collections,
         SUM(IF(action = 'delivery', commission, 0)) as deliveries
  FROM commissions
  WHERE DATE(registered_at) BETWEEN '2023-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2023-01-31 23:59:59'
  GROUP BY origin
) collections ON agencies.code = collections.code
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT destination as code, 
         SUM(IF(action = 'collection', commission, 0)) as collections,
         SUM(IF(action = 'delivery', commission, 0)) as deliveries
  FROM commissions
  WHERE DATE(registered_at) BETWEEN '2023-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2023-01-31 23:59:59'
  GROUP BY destination
) deliveries ON agencies.code = deliveries.code
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT a.code,
         COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN parent.name = 'COMPENSATION' THEN c.amount END), 0) AS COMPENSATION,
         COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN parent.name = 'DIRECT_STRATEGIC_SUPPORT' THEN c.amount END), 0) AS DIRECT_STRATEGIC_SUPPORT,
         COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN parent.name = 'INDRECT_STRATEGIC_SUPPORT' THEN c.amount END), 0) AS INDRECT_STRATEGIC_SUPPORT
  FROM agencies a
  LEFT JOIN compensations c ON a.id = c.agency_id
  LEFT JOIN compensation_categories cc ON cc.id = c.compensation_category_id
  LEFT JOIN compensation_categories parent ON parent.id = cc.parent_id
  WHERE DATE(c.registered_at) BETWEEN '2023-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2023-01-31 23:59:59'
  GROUP BY a.code
) compensations ON agencies.code_ac = compensations.code_ac;
```